# Ubuntu 22.04 stops halfway boot: "failed to start snap daemon"

Tags: boot, gnome, 22.04, amd-processor

My laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome fails halfway the boot process. The following occurs

```
... lots of boot messages...
[ OK ] Started Rule-based manager for devices and files
       Starting Show Plymouth boot screen
[   11.123456] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

... lots of empty lines...

[   12.123456] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[   12.123457] Bluetooth: hci0 reading intel version command failed (-110)
[Failed] Failed to start Snap Daemon
... which is repeated each ~30-60 seconds for a total of 11 times
[Failed] Failed to start Wait until snapd is fully seeded
[Failed] Failed to start Snap Daemon
```

And then presumably hangs. This process takes about 10 minutes.

My laptop is a Tuxedo laptop with an AMD Ryzen 7 5800H processor that has worked reliably till 5 september. On that day I upgraded ubuntu and updated as well some kept back gnome files. I could continue my work without problems but during the new reboot I got these problems.

A remark about bluetooth: As I don't need it is switched it of quite some time ago. I am surprised about the remark trying to read the intel version as I have an AMD CPU.

Can someone point me to some possible solution?

Comment: can you include `systemctl status snapd`?

Comment: How? The system does not boot.

Comment: boot into emergency mode, or you can use a live usb